# Convert Excel column to rows when a specific character is in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column with full of data, and there is no specific pattern, that after 10 or 20 rows I should repeat a new row. So these Index and Offset solutions only can work, if the formula can define the start and finish of each section.

To understand it right I have a column like:

A
B
C
D
- (this breaks a section)
A
C
E
F
G
- (this breaks another row)
B
C
F
G
- (break again)

So it would be fine for me, if every "-" character would start a new line in a table. Is it possible to do it in Excel, or Access, with formula or VBA?

Thank you!

Comment: `Is it possible to do it in Excel, or Access, with formula or VBA?` Yes it is.

Comment: Unable to understand that how you are making combinations,, since C, F  & G are common in both sets?

Comment: @RajeshS It doesn't matter for me, that the letters will be mixed, so it's not necessary, that As have to be under each other, it's okey for me if the rows will be:


ABCD
ACEFG
BCFG

After that I can gather the necessary information from it, I just want it in rows.

Comment: @Gabor,, have U tried Transpose since your data has not pattern !!

Comment: @RajeshS transpose only convert column into row, but I have one column and the goal is to make several rows from this one column, as many rows as "-" character is in the first column (when only "-" in a cell, nothing else).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=FILTERXML("<Group><Element>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,A1:A15),"-","</Element><Element>")&"</Element></Group>","/Group/Element")
```

This uses `TEXTJOIN()` to join all the values in the column (A1:A15 in the formula. It assumes no "-" as the end cell, and that can be achieved by simply selecting the cell above such a last entry to be the end of the range if ending "-" characters always appear.) It doesn't skip any cells even if empty, but if empty cells should be skipped, use `TRUE` for the second parameter in the function.

Then you are going to turn the single element `TEXTJOIN()` array divided into parts by the "-" characters into the same string but with "" in place of the "-" characters. This is to make the string partially ready for use in the `FILTERXML()` function you see. Notice the replacements are all internal to the string, or in other words, appear only inside it, not at either end. If you are familiar at all with HTML, you will know the "</tag name>" form closes a tag and the "" opens a tag.

You then add the opening tag at the beginning (prepend it before the `SUBSTITUTE()` occurs) and the closing tag appends to the... end. So you have opening and closing tag pair around each of the desired groups that the "-" characters used to split apart.

Finally, all those individually tagged elements (See where I got the tag name "" from?) need to be grouped into a single group (See where the tag  comes from?).

Now you have an HTML string that `FILTERXML()` can make sense of and tear into pieces. It takes that string for the first parameter and for the second parameter, you tell it how the tags relate via what's called the "Path"... that is the "/Group/Element" bit at the end.

Hard to understand why Excel set that need up when such a string is very obviously organized a particular way, right? But it was intended to dissect actual live HTML from live websites, not take apart "mundane" strings and there could have been a lot of other tags in such a string of HTML and it would not be so obvious then! Interestingly though, it suggests that if you made a string with multiple tagging, you could have Excel take different sets from the same string using different Path values.

Anyway, `FILTERXML()` likes to give its results in a vertical layout, rows in one column. I believe you would prefer this *[yes, I see in Comments you explicitly ask for rows]*, but if not, if you want a horizontal layout, columns in one row, just wrap the whole thing in a `TRANSPOSE()` function.

Another interesting use of `FILTERXML()` is that you can specify exactly which element of such a group you want, by number (1, 2, 3,... etc.) AND the last one by number (if known) OR by "last" which can be handy.

It can do a wider range of things with strings if you have a working way to insert the internal tag pairs () in the right places.